# Mockito.verify() for org.springframework.ui.Model containing a Map

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, mockito, spring-test

I am writing unit test for get mapping,

```
 @GetMapping("/abc/{Id}/def")
 public String getAbc(@PathVariable String id, Model model) {
     Map map = new HashMap();
     map.put("abc", "abc1");
     map.put("def", "def1");
     model.addAllAttributes(map);
     return "c/a/t";
 }
```

How to verify model part, this is giving me compilation error,

```
 verify(model, times(1)).addAllAttributes(map, argumentCaptor.capture());
```

I know model with single argument can be verified by:

```
verify(model, times(1)).addAttribute(eq("abc"),argumentCaptor.capture());
```

But I have model with map as argument, any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `addAllAttributes` is:

```
Model addAllAttributes(Map<String, ?> attributes);
```

So, it only expects one argument - a `Map`. You can verify this call as follows:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Map> argumentCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Map.class);
verify(model, times(1)).addAllAttributes(argumentCaptor.capture());

Map actual = argumentCaptor.getValue();
assertTrue(actual.containsKey("abc"));
assertEquals("abc1", actual.get("abc"));
```

Or if you can construct the expected Map in your test case then you could just verify as follows:

```
Map expectedMap = new HashMap();
expectedMap.put("abc", "abc1");
expectedMap.put("def", "def1");

verify(model, times(1)).addAllAttributes(expectedMap);
```